# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException : While trying to the run the jar file

Tags: java, exception, jar, nullpointerexception

When i run the command `java -jar MyJar.jar` i get the following errors :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

What errors are these ? What could be the reason i am getting these errors ?

Before I packed the packages in a jar file the scene was :

[image]

Then i packed the above files along with the packages by entering :

```
jar -cf MyJar.jar .\Design\*.class .\InterfaceImplementation\*.class .\Interfaces\*.class .\messenger\*.class Manifest.MF RemoteMethodImpl_Stub.class
```

*NOTE :* When i unpack the jar file there is a folder named `META-INF` which also contains `MANIFEST.MF` but not the name of main class.

*The content of my MANIFEST.MF : `Main-Class : messenger.Messenger`* also tried by putting a forward slash

Comment: To be clear, what was the content of your MANIFEST.MF?

Comment: @ madth3 `Main-Class : messenger/Messenger` Here _messenger_ is the directory and _Messenger_ is the name of main class

Comment: I guess, it should be fully qualified name of class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the jar is not enough to include it in the files, you have to use the `m` option, like

```
jar cmf myManifestFile myFile.jar *.class
```

according to [jar documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html). The order of the options `m` and `f` has to match the order of the parameters for the name of the `MANIFEST` file and the jar file.

Take into account this warning too: *An existing manifest file must end with a new line character.  jar does not parse the last line of a manifest file if it does not end with a new line character.*

Comment: Then i get the following exceptions : `java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyJar.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:170)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1176)`

Comment: When do you get the error? At creating the jar or at executing? If it's the first, you have to follow the order of the options and the parameters. If it's the later, have you verified the MANIFEST.MF inside the jar is correct now?

Answer (score 1):

The error is obviously due to missing main class in manifest...you can specify main class in manifest like this

```
Main-Class: com.Main
```