# can not execute jar file from cmd

Tags: java, cmd, executable-jar

i created an executable jar file using the command `jar cmf <text-file-points-to-main-class> <archive-name.jar>` as a result an executable jar file is produced, but when i attempted to open that executable jar using `java -jar file-name.jar` the following exception is raised

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainClassFromJar(LauncherHelper.java:399)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:463)
```

the `<text-file-points-to-main-class>` actually contains--->Main-Class:hello.java also i tried(hello without .java) 
i can't point what exactly is the problem ? note that the class file works properly

Comment: Please post the exact contents of your manifest file.

Comment: There's a lot of posts about this already, did none of them really help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368349/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-run-jar-file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192647/failing-to-execute-the-jar-file-using-java-jar-command http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287997/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nullpointerexception-while-trying-to-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Main-Class:hello.java

The `Main-Class` value should be the fully qualified *class name*, not the file name, e.g. for

```
package com.example;

public class hello {
```

you need `Main-Class: com.example.hello`